# Restrict List Elements type python 3.7

Tags: python

```
adjlist : List[int] = [1,3,5]
adjlist.append("hello")
print(adjlist)  # -> [1, 3, 5, 'hello']
```

Is there a way to make adjlist to reject strings?

Comment: Not without you manually checking before appending. The code you have here will cause warnings in a good IDE (like Pycharm), and you can tell it to treat such warnings as errors. You can't get full static typing in a dynamically typed language though.

Comment: You could subclass `List` (or perhaps derive a class from [collections.abc.MutableSequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSequence)) but you'd need to ensure all mutating methods checked the type.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html). Consult this code:

```
import array
a = array.array('i', [1, 3, 5])
try:
    a.append("hello")
except TypeError:
    print('invalid value')
print(a)
print(a[1])
```

output is

```
invalid value
array('i', [1, 3, 5])
3
```

In this code `'i'` is the type code of the array, meaning "signed int".