# Python typed list using Generics

Tags: python, generics, typechecking

accordingly to these examples:

1. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types
2. https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#defining-generic-classes

I'm trying to create a class to manage a typed list:

This is my class:

```
T = TypeVar("T")


class FifoQueue(Generic[T]):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.elementsList: list[T] = []

    def push(self, element: T) -> None:
        self.elementsList.append(element)

    def pop(self) -> T:
        return self.elementsList.pop(0) if self.isEmpty() is False else None

    def peek(self) -> T:
        return self.elementsList[0] if self.isEmpty() is False else None

    def isEmpty(self) -> bool:
        return not self.elementsList

    def size(self) -> int:
        return len(self.elementsList)
```

But when I try to execute this test no Type Error or Exception is raised:

```
baseFifoQueue = FifoQueue[int]()
baseFifoQueue.push('hello')
baseFifoQueue.push(1)
```

Comment: What are you expecting to _raise_ that error? The Python interpreter won't do it, that's what tools like MyPy are for. (From the very top of the page you've linked: _"The Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type annotations. They can be used by third party tools such as type checkers, IDEs, linters, etc."_)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restrict List Elements type python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58682178/restrict-list-elements-type-python-3-7)

Comment: MyPy can also tell you of some other problems in your implementation: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=f4c0971de745de0c3822410be38304db.

Comment: @jonrsharpe when I run your example I get exactly what I'm looking for: 'error: Argument 1 to "push" of "FifoQueue" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"'. I'm running the code from Unit Test using  a unittest.TestCase subclass, are there any differences on code execution?

Comment: Yes, the MyPy playground is analysing it _with MyPy_, a type checker that's one of the third party tools referred to above. Your unit tests are not.

Comment: Ok, this is probably why no errors were found! Thank you!